# Subtract multiple columns ignoring NA

Tags: r

I'm fairly new to R and have run into an issue with NA's. This question may have been answered elsewhere but I can't seem to find the answer. I'm trying to do sort of the opposite of `rowSums()` in that I'm trying to subtract `x2` and `x3` from `x1` in order to generate `x4` without NA's. The code I'm currently using is as follows:

```
> x <- data.frame(x1 = 3, x2 = c(4:1, 2:5), x3=c(1,NA))
> x$x4=x$x1-x$x2-x$x3
> x

  x1 x2 x3 x4
1  3  4  1 -2
2  3  3 NA NA
3  3  2  1  0
4  3  1 NA NA
5  3  2  1  0
6  3  3 NA NA
7  3  4  1 -2
8  3  5 NA NA
```

In other words I want to ingore the NA's similar to how `rowSums` allows the `na.rm=TRUE` argument so that I get this result:

```
  x1 x2 x3 x4
1  3  4  1 -2
2  3  3 NA  0
3  3  2  1  0
4  3  1 NA  2
5  3  2  1  0
6  3  3 NA  0
7  3  4  1 -2
8  3  5 NA -2
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `rowSums`:

```
> x$x4 <- x$x1 - rowSums(x[,2:3], na.rm=TRUE)
> x
  x1 x2 x3 x4
1  3  4  1 -2
2  3  3 NA  0
3  3  2  1  0
4  3  1 NA  2
5  3  2  1  0
6  3  3 NA  0
7  3  4  1 -2
8  3  5 NA -2
```

Comment: Any idea how to approach this problem if     x1 & x2 also contained NA's?

Comment: @user3498787 How do you want the `NA`s handled? Are they treated as zeroes (as in my answer) or do you want `NA`s where `x1==NA`?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say if x1 contained NA's. Using your answer and RHelps's answer below it looks like I could combine both to solve it this way:     x$x4 <- ifelse(is.na(x$x1,0,x$x1) - rowSums(x[,2:3], na.rm=TRUE)

Comment: You probably want something like `ifelse(!is.na(x$x1), x$x1 - rowSums(x[,2:3], na.rm=TRUE), 0 - rowSums(x[,2:3], na.rm=TRUE))`

Answer (score 6):

You can use something like this if all columns have NAs -

```
x$x4 <- ifelse(is.na(x$x1),0,x$x1) -ifelse(is.na(x$x2),0,x$x2)-ifelse(is.na(x$x3),0,x$x3)
```

Provided you want to treat NAs as 0. Else you can replace the 0s in the above formula with the value you need.